# Returning dictionary as JSON and successfully accessing it's contents withing JS function - C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` named `finalDictionary` which is created by consolidating multiple Dictionaries.
This is the piece of code which I use to create this Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> finalDictionary= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, int>>();

finalDictionary.Add("Data1", listData1.ToDictionary(x => x.Date, y => y.Value));
finalDictionary.Add("Data2", listData2.ToDictionary(x => x.Date, y => y.Value));
finalDictionary.Add("Data3", listData3.ToDictionary(x => x.Date, y => y.Value));
```

NOTE: `listData1`, `listData2` and `listData3` are all anonymous lists which I'm converting into dictionaries in the above code.

Here's the sample format for each of these dictionaries: (let's consider for `Data1`)

```
Key : 'Data1'
Value : 
        [0] {[6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM, 1]}
        [1] {[6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
        [2] {[6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
        [3] {[7/5/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
        [4] {[7/12/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
        [5] {[7/19/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
        [6] {[7/26/2015 12:00:00 AM, 0]}
```

So each of the dates above are again `Key` part and those numbers are `Value` part.

I return this Dictionary i.e `finalDictionary` as a JSON result from my **controller** method as follows :

```
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = obj.GetDetails()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But when this is returned back to my calling JS ajax it fails throwing the below Internal Server 500 error:

```
jqXHR = {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}, textStatus = "error", errorThrown = "Internal Server Error //and so on
```

Here's my JS code :

```
function loadDetails() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: _WebRoot() + '/Charts/GetDetails',
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            prepareData(response.Records, 'Text Title');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

What modifications do I need to make it work?

**NOTE : I receive the above mentioned error after the data is returned from the Controller and reaches the JS method**

Comment: Perhaps I am being lazy not reading code but might help to get some logging in the C# for the actual exception as the http status code 500 could be anything (firing an exception). Either that or share more of the controller code so we can try and spot where it is throwing an exception.

Comment: Well from the C# side there's no exception, as the Dictionary does get returned from the controller without any error. I think I'm doing something error either with the format of JSON being returned or something wrong on my JS code side.

Comment: 500 error definitely comes from the server (Internal *server* error) - so the `// and so on` part is what you look at to diagnose it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the second `finalDictionary.Add` and check the first 'add' to see if worked properly.

Comment: @wazz yes it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the datatype of **'Key'** ("Date" in my case) element to String fixed the issue.
Initially the "Date" was of **DateTime** **DataType**.

Hence when I was returning my above mentioned dictionary as a **JSONResult** from controller the JS method throwed an error as it was unable to stringify or serialize this dictionary.

So it's advisable to change your Dictionary's **'Key'** element's datatype to **String** or set them as **Objects**.

Here's the error message I was able to debug out (providing this error message as it might help other's who may face such similar issues) :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Type 'System.Collections.Generic. Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[ChatData, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.
```