# get a dictionary from the controller and display the data in JS via AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to get a dictionary from the controller and display the data in JS but all I get is an error message (from an AJAX error function), what am I doing wrong?

```
 $("#Button2").click(function () {
            alert($(this).prop("title"))


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: "@Url.Action("getLastVisit")",                       
                    data:{},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("hh")
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            alert(data.key)
                        }


                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error")

                    }

                })         

            //})


        })
```

controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult getLastVisit()
        {
            List<DateTime> l2 = new List<DateTime>();
            l2 = b.get_updating(Session["Patiant"].ToString());
            Dictionary<DateTime, List< Reccomendations>> mydict = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<Reccomendations>>();
            foreach (var item in l2)
            {
                List<Reccomendations> dg = new List<Reccomendations>();
                dg = b.getReccomendations(item, Session["Patiant"].ToString());
                mydict.Add(item, dg);
            }

            return Json(mydict, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Open your browser dev tools->network tab and see your ajax call is getting 200 OK response. If not check the "response" tab for more detailed error information.

Comment: Do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Did you try what i said in the above comment ? :)

Comment: yes, what i see is this messege:"Not supported for serialization / de-serialization of a dictionary, the keys must be strings or objects." but this what i asking,how do i convert it ?

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning dictionary as JSON and successfully accessing it's contents withing JS function - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241768/returning-dictionary-as-json-and-successfully-accessing-its-contents-withing-js)